# Partially mask email address - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, mask

How can I partially hide email address like this in Javascript?

```
examplemail@domain.com => ex**pl**ai*@domain.com
```

I have modify the below code, but can get the result that I need, it's just return this result:

exam*******@domain.com

```
email.replace(/(.{4})(.*)(?=@)/, function (gp1, gp2, gp3) {
for (let i = 0; i < gp3.length; i++) {
  gp2 += "*";
}
return gp2;
```

});

Comment: I'll would hide the domain too

Comment: Is this for a single email address only? Or can it be a string with more email addresses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could seach for a group of four characters and replace a group of two until you found an `@` sign-

```js
const
    mask = string => string.replace(
        /(..)(.{1,2})(?=.*@)/g,
        (_, a, b) => a + '*'.repeat(b.length)
    );

console.log(mask('examplemail@domain.com'));
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird, it needs a function for getting the length. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to solve your problem:

```
function f(mail) {
  let parts = mail.split("@");
  let firstPart = parts[0];
  let encrypt = firstPart.split("");
  let skip = 2;
  for (let i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i += 1) {
    if (skip > 0) {
      skip--;
      continue;
    }
    if (skip === 0) {
      encrypt[i] = "*";
      encrypt[i + 1] = "*";
      skip = 2;
      i++;
    }
  }
  let encryptedMail = `${encrypt.join("")}@${parts.slice(1)}`;
  return encryptedMail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply do this**

```js
function maskFunc(x) {
    var res = x.replace(/(..)(.{1,2})(?=.*@)/g,
     (beforeAt, part1, part2) => part1 + '*'.repeat(part2.length)
    );  
    
    return res
}

console.log(maskFunc('emailid@domain.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As a regex for the accepted answer, I would suggest making sure to match only a single @ sign by making use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\s@]` matching any char except a whitespace char or an @ itself.

This way you might also use it for multiple email addresses, because using `(?=.*@)` with multiple @ signs can give unexpected results.

```
([^\s@]{2})([^\s@]{1,2})(?=[^\s@]*@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r9xgmN/1)

---

In the pattern that you tried, you matched 4 times any char using `(.{4})`. Repeating 4 chars might be done using a positive lookbehind. Then you could get the match only without groups.

First assert a whitespace boundary to the left. Then start with an offset of 2 chars, optionally repeated by 4 chars.

Then match 1 or 2 chars, asserting an @ to the right.

```js
const partialMask = s => s.replace(
  /(?<=(?<!\S)[^\s@]{2}(?:[^\s@]{4})*)[^\s@]{1,2}(?=[^\s@]*@)/g,
  m => '*'.repeat(m.length)
);
console.log(partialMask("examplemail@domain.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only replace the digits close to the @ and allow it to add * base on the length, you can do this

```
 const separatorIndex = email.indexOf('@');
    if (separatorIndex < 3)
        return email.slice(0, separatorIndex).replace(/./g, '*')
            + email.slice(separatorIndex);

    const start = separatorIndex - Math.round(Math.sqrt(separatorIndex)) - 1;

    const masked = email.slice(start, separatorIndex).replace(/./g, '*');
    return email.slice(0, start) + masked + email.slice(separatorIndex);
```